# Disable Windows 7/8 Alt+TAB *preview* (entirely)

Tags: windows-7, window, thumbnails, alt-tab, transparency

When Alt+TAB-ing Windows shows a list of icon previews, and, after a second or so, shows the actual window selected behind this list (a feature called Aero Peek).

I just want to see that window immediately, and unobstructed by the preview list.

I want that preview list *GONE*. It makes no sense.

How do I do that?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but the way tit normally works makes sense to me -- for example, the preview is good when I'm trying to alt-tab 5 or 10 windows/tabs in from the current one, as its much less annoying to see the previews than having to tab past each full window, one at a time, across multiple monitors, jerking my head around until I find the one I want.  Also, if you hit Alt-Tab and then hold Alt (to keep the preview up) you can also use the mouse to click directly to the window you want, which again can be handy as heck when you've got 15 IE tabs to choose from.

Comment: Thanks. XP has no preview at all but icons and text. That doesn't flash windows and is achievable in W8. But a preview often makes sense: take a peek at the obscured window, than abort the Peek. Yet typically the interesting parts are obscured by the ALT+TAB list.. I'd like to _try_ this, hence my question. Using the mouse isn't an option, we have the taskbar for that (mine is XP-style).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this does it for you- I know this works in Windows 8...

In windows 8, go to "performance options" and uncheck "Enable Peek" (That's what I see it called in Windows 8.1)
I did this, now when I alt-tab through my apps, the alt tab box stays up as do all the windows as I alt-tab (and shift-alt-tab) my way around.

I think there was a similar option in Windows 7.